# select2 not showing options within livewire component

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2, laravel-livewire

I am working with **laravel livewire**.There is a component to update brands and categories of a product. category and brand select option is a **select2** option. **dropdown showing as a select2, but does not show the options**.

This is my component

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Components\MemberArea\Product;

use App\Models\ProductBrand;
use App\Models\ProductCategory;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Livewire\Component;

class UpdateProductBrand extends Component
{
    public $product_id;
    public $product_category_id;
    public $product_brand_id, $categories, $brands, $product;
  

    public function render()
    {
        return view('pages.products.components.update-product-brand');
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->product = Product::get($this->product_id);
        $this->categories = ProductCategory::all();
        $this->brands = ProductBrand::all();
        $this->product_category_id = $this->product->product_category_id;
    }





    public function submit()
    {
        $data = $this->validate();
        $product =  Product::get($this->product_id);
        Product::update($product, $data);
        session()->flash('message', 'Brand Details Updated Successfully.');
       
    }
}
```

This is My Blade

```html
<div class="card-body">
    <form wire:submit.prevent="submit">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <label class="h5">Product Category <sup class="text-danger">*</sup>|<button type="button"
                        id="new-category" class="btn btn-light ">+</button></label>
                <select required class="form-control" wire:model="product_category_id" id="categories_edit">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    @foreach ($categories as $category)
                    <option {{ $product->product_category_id === $category->id ? 'selected' :'' }}
                        value="{{ $category->id }}">{{
                            $category->title }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            @error('product_brand_id')
            <span class="text-danger error">{{ $message }}</span>
            @enderror
            <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <label class="h5">Product Brand <sup class="text-danger">*</sup>| <button type="button" id="new-brand"
                        class="btn btn-light">+</button></label>
                <select class="form-control" wire:model="product_brand_id" id="brands_edit">
                    @foreach ($brands as $brand)
                    <option {{ $product->product_brand_id === $brand->id ? 'selected' :'' }} value="{{ $brand->id }}">
                        {{ $brand->title }}
                    </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            @error('product_category_id')
            <span class="text-danger error">{{ $message }}</span>
            @enderror
            <div class="form-group col-lg-12 text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>

@push('js')


<script>
    document.addEventListener("livewire:load", function (event) {
        window.livewire.hook('afterDomUpdate', () => {
            $('#categories_edit, #brands_edit').select2({
                placeholder: 'Select an option',
            });
        });
    });
  

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#categories_edit').select2();
        $('#brands_edit').select2();
    });
    //set category on select
    $('#categories_edit').on('change', function (e) {
        var category_select = $('#categories_edit').select2("val");
        console.log("category when select= " + category_select);
        @this.product_category_id = category_select;
    });
    //set brand on select
    $('#brands_edit').on('change', function (e) {
        var brand_select = $('#brands_edit').select2("val");
        console.log("brand when select= " + brand_select);
        @this.product_brand_id = brand_select;
    });

</script>

@endpush
```

this is how show it
[image]

when use wire:ignore it also not working. show only dropdown as select2 , but it does not show the options

Comment: you have changed the path of the views in livewire.php file?

Comment: Yes  I did @Prospero